# How to report an bug in calculator

Tags: applications, calculator

How do I report a bug or actually an error in the calculator that comes with Android? The version of Android on my Tab4 is 4.4.2 and 4.1.2 on my Samsung phone. It is the modulus function -- '%'. For example on paper if you divide 24 by 7 you get a remainder of 3, which is the correct modulus. The Android calculator puts a 'x' after the '%' and in front of the number you are trying to mod by. You end up with a 1.68. The only way this could be correct is if the creators of the calculator had something else in mind for the modulus symbol, which probably shouldn't be done. Maybe use '%x' on the button would be more accurate.

Comment: As MehulJoisar pointed out in his answer, the % is for percent calculations. The stock calculator of Android, and of every phone I've ever had, can't even do [order of operations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations), but simply evaluates from left to right. Modulo arithmetic is more advanced than that, so don't expect it in a stock calculator any time soon.

Answer (score 4):

It is **not for modulo** , it is for percentage.

i.e. : if you consider 24 as 100% value and you want to find 7% of 24 then,
**(24*7)/100=1.68**

Answer (score 3):

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/list
(you can report here and add it to the bug tracking list){{what you may need}}

MOST USER FRIENDLY
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.robotmedia.bugreporter
(bug reporting app on google play)